# How can I get an iPhone through Apple's iPhone Upgrade Program on my family's Verizon plan?

Tags: iphone, upgrade

My current iPhone is on a two-year contract with Verizon that makes me eligible for an upgrade in January, with a plan that I share with my family. I'm really interested in Apple's iPhone Upgrade Program, so I was wondering, is it possible to get an iPhone through the iUP, keep my current number, and put the iPhone on my family's plan that has, until now, been all iPhones purchased through Verizon? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, virtually any postpaid Verizon customer can sign up for the iPhone Upgrade Program through Apple's web site or in store. (So can Sprint and AT&T customers, although T-Mobile is currently in-store only.)

This is separate from any agreements you have with Verizon, and you will still have to finish paying off your current phone with them.

Comment: But would the phone be able to replace my current Verizon-contracted phone on my family's data plan?

Comment: You should be able to use it with your plan as long as you enter your plan info when you sign up.